OpenRewrite: How to run a recipe that depends on the execution of a previous recipe in a recipeList?
I have the following recipe:
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: my.company.recipe.UpgradeInternalComponents
displayName: UpgradeInternalComponents
description: UpgradeInternalComponents
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.maven.ChangePropertyValue:
      key: my-libs.version
      newValue: 5.0.0 # it was 4.3.5 before
  - org.openrewrite.maven.AddManagedDependency:
      groupId: my.company
      artifactId: my-libs-bom # was introduced on 5.0.0
      version: ${my-libs.version}
      type: pom
      scope: import
      addToRootPom: true

However my-libs-bom managed dependency isn't added and I get the following warning:
[WARNING] Failed to download my.company:my-libs-bom:4.3.5. Attempted URIs:
  - file:///C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/my/company/my-libs-bom/4.3.5/my-libs-bom-4.3.5.pom
  - https://internal.maven.repo/maven/my/company/my-libs-bom/4.3.5/my-libs-bom-4.3.5.pom

I expected that after running org.openrewrite.maven.ChangePropertyValue I would have the updated value to use on org.openrewrite.maven.AddManagedDependency.
I tried adding causesAnotherCycle: true to the recipe but it made no difference.

Hmm; AddManagedDependency does not allow using a ${...} property as a version as far as I know: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/25d374b7c9500c6651dff001f62ea15cff4f9702/rewrite-maven/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/maven/AddManagedDependency.java#L54-L57

Do you think it should allow or should I avoid this, @Tim?

Nevertheless, it handled well the variable interpolation - the problem is that it is still using the old value.

@Tim, sorry for another comment. I made a test with AddManagedDependency and ${...}, and it worked. In fact it replaced the variable with the value.
Interestingly, in this test I also tested the case of adding an property and the managed dependency using the variable after, and it also worked. I'll make some more tests and let you know.

All good. I don't have a lot of time to dive in this week, so logging an issue might be best
